# My flutter application not show any image in web browser

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to place an image in my app for test. it runs good in emulator but in web browser like chrome it shows FormatException: Message corrupted.
I checked my pubspec.yaml and everything is looks fine!
here is my codes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [Image(image: AssetImage('assets/logo_5x5.png'))],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and here is my pubspec.yaml:

```
name: anything
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none'
version: 0.1.0

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.6 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/logo_5x5.png
```

[image]

Comment: make sure its not a corrupt file and it can be rendered in browser.

Comment: @Vettiyanakan I tried different images. but still the same error.

Comment: @Nagual not related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-renderer html
```